# Convergence in probability with double limits

Tags: random-variable, asymptotic-covariance

Suppose you have a sequence of random variables $
\left\lbrace X_{i}\right\rbrace_{i=1,...,n}$ which converges in probability to a random variable $X$, shown by $ X_n \ \xrightarrow{p}\ X$ as n goes to $\infty$.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon) = 0$$

Now, suppose we can furteher obtain a sequence of random variables for each n $
\left\lbrace X_{j,n}\right\rbrace_{j=1,...,m}$ such that $ X_{m,n} \ \xrightarrow{p}\ X_n$ as m goes to $\infty$.

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} P(|X_{m,n}-X_{n}|>\varepsilon) = 0$$

My question is, may I define $ X_{m,n} \ \xrightarrow{p}\ X$ as both m and n go to $\infty$ at the same time (double limit)?

$$ \lim \limits_{\substack{%
     m \to \infty\\
     n \to \infty}} P(|X_{m,n}-X|>\varepsilon) = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I found the solution in the following
[Appendix on DOUBLE ASYMPTOTICS](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119079507.app3)

See equation C.9

Therefore it is sufficient that $m/n$ (or $n/m$) converges to a constant to ensure the double asymptotic convergence.